# How can I change database name conventions in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to change the default database naming conventions in my Laravel app. By default, Laravel uses snake case for database table and column names. But I want to use Pascal Case for table names and i want to use camel Case for fields.

So a table name of `Users` instead of `users`, and field names `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, and `deletedAt` instead of `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `deleted_at`.

I know I can change these on a per-model basis using the `$table` property but I'd like to change the default without having to modify each model.

Are there any settings like [Symfony's `NamingStrategy`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/namingstrategy.html) in Laravel?

Comment: you don't need to change any way that it does things ... the conventions are only used when you don't configure otherwise ... so for a Model you can define what table it uses, for relationships you can define the keys and table (many to many), timestamps, etc etc ... not sure what else would be an issue .. you could have your own base Model that you can customize and have your Models extend from

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the code for `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getTable()` it's pretty straightforward:

```php
public function getTable()
{
    return $this->table ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this)));
}
```

Same for `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps::getCreatedAtColumn()`:

```php
public function getCreatedAtColumn()
{
    return static::CREATED_AT;
}
```

So create your own class that extends `Model` and override that behaviour:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Model extends BaseModel
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';
    const DELETED_AT = 'deletedAt';

    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->table ?? Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this));
    }
}
```

Now, just have your models extend `App\Models\Model` instead of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new model that you extend your models with.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ModelWithPascalCase extends Model
{   
    const DELETED_AT = 'deletedAt';
    const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';

    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->table ?? Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this));
    }
}
```

If you want to make Laravel generate your models extending this, you can do it by editing stubs.

Run

```
artisan stub:publish
```

then edit `stubs/model.stub` by replacing `Model` with your `ModelWithPascalCase`.

After that, when you run

```
artisan make:model User
```

you get your `User` model extended by `ModelWithPascalCase`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stubs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#stub-customization) for that. Also if you named your table in Pascal Case just use `$table` property in model which need to be sync with that table.

Comment: And for example?! (what would be the command which creates something like what OP asks).